# SoapUI/Groovy - How to copy a node?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I just want to use groovy script in SoapUI to copy a simple node and rename it. But I don't have any clue on how to do that.

The input xml is like that :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <a>
      <aa>...</aa>
    </a>
    <a>
      <aa>...</aa>
    </a>
    <b>
      <bb>...</bb>
    </b>
    <b>
      <bb>..</bb>
    </b>
  </soap:Body>
```

I just need for each `<b>` to copy `<bb>` to `<bb2>` :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <a>
      <aa>...</aa>
    </a>
    <a>
      <aa>...</aa>
    </a>
    <b>
      <bb>...</bb>
      <bb2>...</bb2>
    </b>
    <b>
      <bb>..</bb>
      <bb2>...</bb2>
    </b>
  </soap:Body>
```

Because there are multiple "b" fields, I can't use property transfer with XPath tranformation, so I need to use groovy script, but I don't find any help on that specific purpose.

Does anyone can give me some hints ?

I have tried with daggett answer but my input is a SoapUI request/response.

```
def requestHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "WSCall#Request" )

def xclone(Node n){
  return new XmlParser().parseText(XmlUtil.serialize(n))
}

for( item in requestHolder.getDomNodes( "//b" )){
  item.depthFirst().each{e->
    if(e.name()=='bb'){
      def e2 = xclone(e)
      e2.name = 'bb2'
      e.parent()?.append( e2 )
    }
  }
}
```

but I obtain a `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj.depthFirst() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] error at line: 34`

with

```
requestHolder.getDomNodes( "//b" ).each{e->
  if(e.name()=='bb'){
    def e2 = xclone(e)
    e2.name = 'bb2'
    e.parent()?.append( e2 )
  }
}
```

I obtain an `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot read write-only property: name`

Comment: [`requestHolder.getDomNodes`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/XmlHolder.html#getDomNodes-java.lang.String-) returns [DOM Nodes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) and it's not the same as groovy nodes. So you have to check corresponding documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def root = new XmlParser().parseText('''<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <a>
      <aa>...</aa>
    </a>
    <b>
      <bb>111</bb>
    </b>
    <b>
      <bb><cc>222</cc></bb>
    </b>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>''')

def xclone(Node n){
    return new XmlParser().parseText(XmlUtil.serialize(n))
}

root.depthFirst().each{e->
    if(e.name()=='bb'){
        def e2 = xclone(e)
        e2.name = 'bb2'
        e.parent()?.append( e2 )
    }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(root)
```

results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <a>
      <aa>...</aa>
    </a>
    <b>
      <bb>111</bb>
      <bb2>111</bb2>
    </b>
    <b>
      <bb>
        <cc>222</cc>
      </bb>
      <bb2>
        <cc>222</cc>
      </bb2>
    </b>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```